# Store Values of Cart in Database

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, cart

i am developing a e-commerce project in Codeigniter. I want that any user can add products in cart but when he want to checkout he has to logged in the website after that he can checkout. But when i tried this after user login the cart data is lost. How can i store the data before the checkout so that data in the cart not lost.  for solving this i have tried another way that I have stored the cart data in the data base . For storing cart data to database i have used the code below :-
Controller code

```
class Shopping_Cart extends CI_Controller {
public $cart_id = "";
 function add_to_cart()
      {$data = array(
                        'id'    => $this->input->post('product_id'), 
                        'name'  => $this->input->post('product_name'), 
                        'price' => $this->input->post('product_price'), 
                        'qty'   => 1, 
                        "image" =>$this->input->post('product_image'), 
                      );
            $this->cart->insert($data);
       if($this->cart_id)
        {
            $this->updatecarttodb($this->cart->contents());                     
        }
        else
        {           
            $this->addcarttodb($this->cart->contents());
        }       

         echo $this->view_cart(); 
       }
private function addcarttodb($cartdata)
    {
        $cart_id = $this->Cart_model->addtoCart($cartdata);
        $cookie = array(
                            'name'   => 'cart_id',
                            'value'  => $cart_id,
                            'expire' => (365*60*60*24),
                            'domain' => '',
                            'path'   => '/',
                            'prefix' => '',
                            'secure' => FALSE
                        );
        $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
    }
    private function updatecarttodb($cartdata)
    {
        $this->Cart_model->updateCart($this->cart_id,$cartdata);        
    }
```

Model Code

```
function addtoCart($cartData)
{
  $cartData = array("cart_data"=>serialize($cartData));
  $this->db->insert('tbltmpcart',$cartData);     
  return $this->db->insert_id();
}

function updateCart($cart_id,$cartData)
{
  if($cart_id == "")return;
  if($cartData != "")
   {
     $cartData = serialize($cartData);
   }
    $updateData = array("cart_data"=>$cartData);
    $this->db->where("cart_id",$cart_id);   
    $this->db->update('tbltmpcart',$updateData);           
}

function getCartContents($cart_id)
{
  $this->db->where("cart_id",$cart_id);
  $result = $this->db->get('tbltmpcart');
  if($result && $result->num_rows())
  {
    $retdata = $result->result_array();                
    if($retdata[0]['cart_data'] != "1" && $retdata[0]['cart_data'] != "")
    {
      return @unserialize($retdata[0]["cart_data"]);
    }     
  }
  return "";
}
```

my problem is that  $cart_id  value not retain it is lost so i can not use further. If there is any problem in the code the try to correct my code.

Comment: may be there is a problem in you user login script. check if login script is not destroying the session before or after user login.

Comment: i have checked the login script . login is working properly.In my website any user can add products in the cart but if the user is not registered or registered user not logged in he can not checkout. for check out user have to logged in. my problem start the value stored in the cart before user logged in not retain in the cart after user logged in the site.